# Is there a way I can manually update client side contents after sign-up

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, reactjs

I’m a front end dev on my way to backend and this is a personal project. It was meant to be static so all users see the same information on their page but now I want to be able to change some details based on the clients who signs up. For example. All users were meant to see a $20 bill for a community project but now I want to be able to increase or decrease that amount on different client user page.

Comment: That's called a dynamic web application. With Javascript, your frontend will make a request to the backend for data and update the page accordingly.

Comment: it does not have to be javascript but @CarloR is right about it being called a dynamic web application

Comment: Yes, it’s gonna be dynamic now and that’s why I’m having issues. From the onset it was meant to be kinda static. But plans changed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok peww. I can't explain all of it in one single post but what are talking about is a database and backend code like php or node.js etc....
is a dynamic website rather than static cuz things change

if you want to take time and learn about it i recommend you check youtube '[Dani Krossing](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzyuZJ8zZ-Lhfnz41DG5qLw) is a good php teacher ' or w3schools both have great free courses but if you dont want to spend time learning and you need your project done like today you will need a backend dev to help you learn and do it for you.

I am not advertising myself but if you want i will do it for you for free cuz i like working on random projects.

Comment: Thanks DB_cont. I’ve been looking at Dani Krossing videos but somehow I haven’t been able to find any that solves my problem. Maybe you can share a link ? Thanks. And I’d be happy if you could put me through it too, think that’d be the best way forward.

Comment: @orjibenjamin i will be offline for a few hours so maybe ill be back in 8-10 hrs then i will help you code your backend :)

Comment: Great! I’ll send you a message. Thank you.

Comment: @orjibenjamin can you send me the room link I lost it lol.